# Unable to convert signals data from ecg to CSV in wfdb package

Tags: python

I have ecg signals data in folder with each patient id.  I tried using rdsamp function from WFDB(Wave form Database) package in python for converting signal data to CSV file for all patients. CSV file gets created without any data.  What am i doing wrong?

Following is my code.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import wfdb

os.chdir('/home/ecg/ecg-db-patientwise/')

from os import listdir, mkdir, system
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join, exists

dir = '/home/ecg/ecg-patientwise/'
#Create folder
dir_out = dir + 'csv/'
if not exists(dir_out):
    mkdir(dir_out)

records = [f for f in listdir(dir) if isfile(join(dir, f)) if(f.find('.dat') != -1)]

for r in records:
    
    command = 'rdsamp -r'  + dir + r[:-4] + 'rdsamp -c -H -f 0 -v >' + dir_out + r[:-4] + '.csv'
    print(command)
    system(command)
```

I get below message of files being created but all the csv files created in subfolder do not have data and is blank.

rdsamp -r/home/ecg/ecg-patientwise/189s0309lre rdsamp -c -H -f 0 -v >/home/ecg/ecg-patientwise/csv/189s0309lre.csv
rdsamp -r/home/ecg/ecg-patientwise/276s0526re rdsamp -c -H -f 0 -v >/home//ecg/ecg-patientwise/csv/276s0526re.csv

I have also tried converting to text by changing parameters of the command and even text files gets created with no data in subfolder.  My code for converting text was.

```
for r in records:
    
    command = 'rdsamp -r'  + dir + r[:-4] + 'rdsamp -H -f 0 -v >' + dir_out + r[:-4] + '.txt'
    print(command)
    system(command)
```

Comment: Can anyone help on my above question.